# What does $||x||$ mean?

Tags: linear-algebra

I am having trouble understanding the definition of this symbol. What is the definition of this symbol? Is $||x||$ equivalent to the magnitude of x?

Comment: What is $x$? A vector?

Comment: That's most likely the norm in a normed vector space.

Comment: Yes, it is equivalent to the magnitude.

Comment: @Kaster Yes x is a vector

Comment: Surely,This is  generalized of the concept of absolute value on $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Answer (score 2):

In order to define how close two vectors or two matrices
are, and in order to define the convergence of sequences
of vectors or matrices, we can use the notion of a norm $(\|\|)$.

A norm on a vector space $V$ is a function from $V$ to $\mathbb{R_+}$ ( set of nonnegative real numbers) which satisfies certain conditions.

if $V = \mathbb{R}$ then $\|x\| = |x|$, absolute value of $x$.

Also note that We require some method to measure the ‘magnitude’ of a vector and so 
the concept of a ‘length’ of a vector in 3D  is generalized to $n$ dimensions by defining a norm. The norm is a measure of the size of the vector x.

Comment: This is a bit inaccurate. If $V=\mathbb{R}$, then $\|x\|:=k|x|$ defines a norm for any $k>0$.

Comment: @user1551 You are correct but I haven't claimed that this is the only possible norm on $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Hmm, you have. You said that "if $V=R$ **then** $\|x\|=|x|$". This is an implication. Although this is no big deal (and I think your answer is good), the statement is inaccurate.

Comment: @user1551 Dear if you think so, I wouldn't mind if you edit it. :)

Answer (score 0):

It denotes NORM in a vector space.

You can get all the information on **NORM** [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_%28mathematics%29).